# Copying Data from 1 table to another , the second table has 2 extra columns with data that must be inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server

Copying data from 1 table to another, the second table has 2 extra columns with data that must be inserted.
I know I must use an insert into statement and possibly make it nested ,also maybe use @ for variables or something my knowledge is limited and I need to do this in a single query.
There can't be nulls

My current code that isn't working:

```
INSERT INTO SampleExtraTable_2 (SampleID, SampleName, SampleEmail)
SELECT *
       (
       SELECT Extra1,Extra2
       FROM SampleExtraTable_2  
       Values('b','r');
       )
FROM SampleTable_1
WHERE 1 = 1
```

SampleExtraTable_2 has the following fields all defined as char(10), (SampleID, SampleName, SampleEmail,Extra1,Extra2)

SampleTable_1 two has the same fields except the extras and definition amounts are all char(10)

[image: Pic 1]

[image: pc 2 extra]

[image: Results example]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre trying to insert NULL values.

```
   SELECT Extra1,Extra2
   FROM SampleExtraTable_2
```

Your inner select query is returning NULL.

You can insert 'dta', 'dta2' values as a string to your new table like below. (if they are constant)

```
INSERT INTO SampleExtraTable_2 (SampleID, SampleName, SampleEmail, Extra1, Extra2)
SELECT SampleID, SampleName, SampleEmail, 'dta', 'dta2'
FROM SampleTable_1
```

Comment: Ill give it a try, thanks

Comment: Let me know if i can help

Comment: will do thank you